# How do I add new site/server_name in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm just starting to explore nginx on my ubuntu 10.04. I installed nginx and I'm able to get the "Welcome to Nginx" page on localhost. However I'm not able to add a new `server_name`.

Even when I make the changes in `site-available/default`. I also tried reloading/restarting nginx, but nothing works.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you add the server_name?  Give an example of what you are setting and what request you are doing.

Comment: you can try easyengine (http://goo.gl/Wzidcu) to install php, musql and nginx all at once can create websites.
It automatically create nginx configuration and webroot.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To build on mark's answer, Debian/Ubuntu distros default configuration file has an `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` directive with site configuration file stored in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, a default site is usually included in that dir.

For examples beyond the default config, follow [nginx beginner's guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) or see [wiki.nginx.org](http://wiki.nginx.org) for more details.

After creating a new configuration in `sites-available`, create a symbolic link with this command, assuming that your conf file is named "myapp" and nginx is at /etc/nginx (could also be at /usr/local/etc/nginx):

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp
```

By the way, you could always create your conf file directly in sites-enabled but the recommended way above allows you to "enable and disable" sites on the server very quickly without actually moving/deleting your conf files.

P.S: [Don't trust the tutorials: check your configuration!](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/)

P.P.S: You can use the command `nginx -t` to test your sites conf and `nginx -s reload` to reload the conf.

Comment: Just wanted to add that nginx_ensite and nginx_dissite (https://github.com/perusio/nginx_ensite) might be helpful. http://serverfault.com/questions/424452/nginx-enable-site-command

Comment: Google brought me to this page... the circular reference wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't updated this answer for a while, and the google link was broken. Let me know if this is more readable?

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to add another site in Nginx in Ubuntu is to copy the sites-available/default file to sites-available/new-site-name, then create a symbolic link in sites-enabled to sites-available/new-site-name.

In the new configuration file, you need to edit the `listen` and `server` directives. Use listen to specify the IP address and port, and the server directive to specify the hostnames. For more details, see [HttpCoremodule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule).